# Java MSI silent installer

Tags: java, powershell, windows-installer, synchronous

Hello i'm having issues with this line of code I been working on, for some reason is not working anymore I'm trying to invoke the MSI installer silently and wait till it's done so I can execute next line of code I had it working but now is not, I tried executing start-process and using the -wait parameter but it's returning with an error message, and when I call "msiexec.exe" it doesn't have a -wait parameter

```
msiexec.exe /i "C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi" /QN TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Done.`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Start-Sleep -s 2



  start-process msiexec.exe  "/i C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi" -wait /QN TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log" 
     Write-Host -NoNewLine "Done.`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
      Start-Sleep -s 2

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/QN'.
At line:1 char:1

    + start-process msiexec.exe  "/i C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.ms ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Silent installer command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914609/java-silent-installer-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msiexec.exe` is unusual in that, while it has an extensive CLI (command-line interface) with many supported parameters, it is a *GUI*-subsystem executable that runs independently of any calling console.

**PowerShell runs GUI-subsystem executables *asynchronously* when you invoke them directly**; that is, unlike with *console*-subsystem executables, it *doesn't wait for the executable to terminate* before continuing.

While **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Wait`** is indeed the typical way to **invoke a GUI-subsystem executable *synchronously***, there is also a **convenient *shortcut***:

If you **pipe to [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null)**:<sup>[1]</sup>

- **PowerShell *will* wait for the executable('s process) to terminate**, even if it is a GUI-subsystem application.

  - Note: **If you know that the GUI application produces *no stdout output* - and *not* doing so is typical - you can also pipe to `Wait-Process` for better conceptual clarity** or, if you want **to *suppress* any stdout output, pipe to `Out-Null`**  (again, see footnote [1])
- Additionally, **the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) will properly reflect the process' exit code** (which not many *GUI*-subsystem executables meaningfully set, but `misexec.exe` does), allowing you to infer *success* (exit code `0`) vs. *failure* (any *nonzero* exit code), by convention.

  - That said, **`msiexec.exe` uses two *nonzero* exit codes that *also* indicate - qualified - success** (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes) for a full list of exit / error codes and their description):

    - `3010` (`ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED`)
    - `1641` (`ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_INITIATED`)

Therefore, you can use the following:

```bash
# Note the `| Write-Output` at the end of the line, which ensures *synchronous* execution.
msiexec.exe /i "C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi" /QN TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log" | Write-Output
$exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Installation finished with exit code $exitCode."
```

---

**Alternatively**, pass the `msiexec` command line to ***`cmd.exe`* via its `/c` parameter**, which:

- *implicitly* makes the call synchronous (and also sets `$LASTEXITCODE`)
- ***preserves the original quoting*, which is necessary if you pass property values with *embedded spaces***, e.g. `MYPROP="foo bar"` is then passed exactly as such, whereas *PowerShell* would convert this argument to `"MYPROP=foo bar"` when it rebuilds the actual command line behind the scenes, which `msiexec.exe` doesn't recognize.

```bash
cmd /c @"
msiexec.exe /i "C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi" /QN TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
"@
$exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Installation finished with exit code $exitCode."
```

Note the use of a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@` in this example to make embedded quoting easier.

---

The above solutions are more convenient alternatives to the following **`Start-Process -Wait` solution**, which additionally uses `-PassThru` to pass an object representing the launched process through, so that its `.ExitCode` property can be checked:

```bash
$exitCode = (Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru msiexec.exe @'
/i "C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi" /QN TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
'@).ExitCode

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Installation finished with exit code $exitCode."
```

Note how ***all* arguments for `misexec.exe` are passed *as a single string* to `Start-Process`** (using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) for readability here), which positionally binds to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

While the `-ArgumentList` parameter technically accepts an *array* of arguments - i.e. allows you to pass arguments *individually* - a long-standing bugs makes that unadvisable - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your `Start-Process -Wait` call failed, because you ended up passing *more than two* positional arguments:

```bash
start-process msiexec.exe  "/i ..." -wait /QN ...
```

- `msiexec.exe` positionally binds to the `-FilePath` parameter.
- Only the `"/i ..."` argument positionally argument binds to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.
- Since no other `Start-Process` parameters support positional binding, `Start-Process` doesn't know what to do with `/QN` (and all subsequent positional (unnamed) arguments), which is what the error message in your question indicates.

Note: If you did want to pass parameters *individually* - which is best avoided, as stated above - you'd have to pass them  as an *array*, separated by `,`
(`Start-Process -Wait msiexec.exe '/i', ...`)

---

<sup>[1] Note that *any* command in a subsequent pipeline segment works to ensure synchronous execution, because PowerShell always has to wait for the preceding segment's command to terminate, so as to ensure that all input has been received; While it ultimately doesn't matter what command you choose, `Write-Output`, which in this case will *typically* be a no-op, has the advantage of passing stdout output through so that it becomes visible / can be captured, *if* the GUI application at hand produces such output, which is rare (append `2>&1` to the GUI-application call to also capture *stderr* output). As [Bender the Greatest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584676/bender-the-greatest) points out, some GUI applications do so in order to produce *debugging output*, by explicitly [*attaching to the caller's console*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943162/584676). If you'd rather *suppress* this information, pipe to `Out-Null` instead.</sup>

Comment: Neat trick with piping to `Out-Null` to block execution. Is this behavior only with `Out-Null` or does this extend to piping the down the pipeline in general? E.g. would piping to `Write-Output` or `Write-Verbose` work?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. GUI applications can be made to write to STDOUT and STDERR, and if run in the console will write output to the console. I used to work on software which did this. Although admittedly I may be remembering this backwards, that project might have been built as a console application that then invoked GUI components; which would support what you said as it would still technically be built as a console application.

Comment: However, [is it still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943162/584676) to write to the console using an executable built Windows Application

Comment: I've done this in two cases: programs which have already been defined as GUI applications which then need to later provide console output. Changing the program type could be considered a breaking change in some contexts in part due to the differing execution behavior. The second case is to provide debug or trace level output to a program already defined as a GUI application. Usually I would agree and not recommend this approach, but the suite of products I was working on at the time was somewhat bespoke functionality and changing the program to console broke some things for key customers.

Comment: So while uncommon, and maybe not recommended, piping to something other than `Out-Null` would catch these (technically correct, the best kind of "correct" `;)`) edge cases.

Comment: I don't understand; external programs STDOUT get written to the success stream. Why would it matter whether it's a GUI or console application as long as you either redirect process output (not possible directly with `Start-Process`, you would need to go full `[Thread]::Start(ProcessStartInfo)` for this) or specify `Start-Process -NoNewWindow`?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, I stand corrected: stdout output from a directly invoked GUI that is forced into synchronous execution with an additional pipeline segment _is_ passed through the success output stream, so I've changed the answer to recommend `Write-Output` instead - please see the footnote. Note that with `Start-Process` you'd use `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardErr` to _capture_ such output; to simply _see_ it in the current console (without being able to capture it), yes, `-NoNewWindow` works.

Comment: Now I recall; `-RedirectStandard*` outputs to a file. This works but I prefer variables especially if I need to run a process multiple times. Oftentimes I absolutely don't want output going to a file and would rather keep it in memory. `[Process]::Start(ProcessStartInfo)` lets you read STDOUT and STDERR from the returned `Process` object instead. I can't recall, but I *think* I've tried outputting to a `Variable:\ ` path and was met with an error.

Comment: Confirmed, using `Start-Process ping -ArgumentList google.com -RedirectStandardOutput Variable:\pingOutput` is met with an error: `Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Variable) cannot open a file`. My guess is `Start-Process` explicitly opens a `FileStream` which the `Variable` provider doesn't support.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, yes, these parameters only support capturing stream output _in files_ (and you can't _merge_ streams unless you call _via a shell_ and make `2>&1` part of the shell command). It would indeed be nice to be able to capture in _variables_, as direct execution can do (but not separately with `2>`);allowing namespace notation (`variable:output`) wherever file paths are expected would make for a great _future enhancement_, discussed in [GitHub issue #5184](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5184) and [#4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo, @JakeRobb.

Answer (score 1):

`msiexec.exe` is a GUI tool, and Windows CLI (Command Prompt or PowerShell) will not block by default. Conversely, console applications will block by default. In PowerShell, you can alter this default behavior (as well as gain additional control and information about the child process) by using `Start-Process`.

> **Note:** This answer focuses on `Start-Process` but the equivalent way to force a program to wait before continuing in the Command Prompt or `.bat` script is
>
> ```
> start "title" /WAIT [command/program] [parameters]
> ```
>
> Note that the "title" can be a blank string `""`.

---

Since you've updated your question with your `Start-Process` attempt, it failed because you provided the `-Wait` parameter in the middle of the `-ArgumentList` arguments. `-ArgumentList` is defined specially, so all remaining positional arguments following it are considered part of it. The problem is when you stick another named parameter there, you've now broken the chain of arguments. The solution is shown below, but make sure you provide the `-ArgumentList` arguments without separating them with other parameters to `Start-Process`:

```
$msiExecArgs = @(
  '/i',
  'C:\MagtekCC\Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144.msi',
  '/QN',
  '/L*V', 'C:\Temp\msilog.log',
  'TRANSFORMS="jre1.8.0_144.mst'
) -join ' '

Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList $msiExecArgs
```

This works in the following way:

- Create an array of `msiexec` arguments. This can be an array of each space-separated argument you would normally pass to `msiexec.exe` in the same order you would specify interactively. Alternatively, you can also provide it as a single string. Read the sub-point below to understand why I declare this as an array only to `-join` it to a string.

  - [Due to this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) providing arguments as a string is recommended, and is why I took the array arguments and use `-join` to create a space-delimited string out of them. The array code is a bit easier to manage as now we don't have to use `+=` (gross and not recommended) or `StringBuilder` (recommended over `+=` but overkill for building an array of arguments) and we still get the string which avoids the bug.
- `-Wait` tells `Start-Process` to block further execution until the program exits.
- `-ArgumentList` is used to pass our array of `$msiExecArgs` arguments to `msiexec`.

---

> **Note:** A prior revision of this answer incorrectly stated that `Start-Process` needs
> `-Wait:$false` in order not to block on execution for CLI applications. While the default behavior for external programs is to block for CLI and not block for GUI, `Start-Process` actually ignores this and does not block by default regardless of the program type. Use the `-Wait` parameter to block, and omit or provide `-Wait:$false` not to block.

Conversely, if you wanted to run a CLI program in the background, do the same thing as above but omit the `-Wait` parameter instead (you will probably want to check the result as well which requires a little extra elbow-grease with `-PassThru` so we can check whether it's done and its exit code):

```
$p = Start-Process ping -PassThru -ArgumentList www.google.com

# Do other stuff, then check the result when ready
Write-Host "Checking that ping.exe has finished"
while( !$p.HasExited ) {

  # Wait 1 second before checking again
  Start-Sleep 1
}

if( $p.ExitCode -ne 0 ) {
  Write-Error "ping failed with exit code $($p.ExitCode)"
}
```

- Using `ping.exe` as an example, we run it through `Start-Process`. `ping.exe` is a console application, and would normally block until execution completes.
- `-PassThru` is used to tell `Start-Process` to return the `Process` object. `Start-Process` does not return anything by default, but in this case we later want to check that this is done running and whether it succeeded. This is optional but required to check the result later on.
- The `while` loop waits for `$p.HasExited` to return true. `Process.HasExited` is used to determine whether the process execution has finished, regardless of success or failure.
- The `if` statement checks that the exit code of the `Process` object returned `0`. As a matter of standard, a program can normally be considered successful if it returns `0`, though you can specify an array of acceptable exit codes should a program use other codes for different end states.

---

There are other things you can do with the process object as well, play around with it. However, while `Start-Process` can be a powerful tool it is often overused, unnecessarily complicating code which does not need it. While your use case for MSIEXEC is a perfect example of when to use it, oftentimes you can simplify the use of `Start-Process` by omitting it altogether and relying instead on the call operator `&` to execute programs.

Comment: thanks for the lengthy response as well as being informative very helpful I appreciated a lot, I went ahead and test it and it seems to be working as intended but I'm curious to know why mine using the start process msiexec.exe didn't. I have uploaded the error code on the main post.

Comment: Two reasons: you stuck -Wait between msiexec arguments, it should be a direct parameter off of Start-Process, and also you did not provide the -ArgumentList parameter as an array of strings. See the code block where I set $msiExecArgs and the explanation following it, and compare it to your code. If you still don't understand, I will try to explain further when I'm not on mobile.